# How to switch visibility GONE and VISIBLE in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, visibility

I want to switch between visibility `GONE` and `VISIBLE`.
This is really easy to achieve in Android development, but I don't know how to use the same approach in **Swift**

I tried this code to set a label as gone:

```
// set the width constraint to 0
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:  self.labelShortDescription, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.labelShortDescription.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

// set the height constraint to 0
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:  self.labelShortDescription, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.labelShortDescription.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

Comment: you mean to show and hide an object?

Comment: i want show and gone view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change visibility with change isHidden and change constraint value

it works :

```
func visibilityLogo(visibility : Bool){

        self.img.isHidden = !visibility
        self.viewImageConstrain.constant = visibility ? 50 : 0
        self.viewConttrainParent.constant = visibility ? 50 : 0
        self.img.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Please provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: I added an answer which explains the idea here in more detail. That answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60298013/826946

Answer (score 5):

INVISIBLE:

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout
>   purposes.

To achieve that in iOS:

```
yourView.alpha = 0
```

GONE:

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes.

To achieve that in iOS:

```
yourView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: thanks , this a problem first remove superView and can not again show view

Comment: better solution is to have a height constraint on the view, use an IBOutlet to connect that constraint to your code, and set the constraint's "constant" to 0 when you want the view to be "gone", and put it back to the regular height when you want it visible. I will try to write this up below.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an `UIView` extension in swift to manage the views visibility similarly to the android SDK approach for views visibility.

This extension automatically adds the required constraints to collapse the view vertically, horizontally, or both. These constraints are never added multiple times and they're only needed when the visibility type is **gone**, **goneY** or **goneX**. They're automatically set as **not active** when the visibility is dynamically changed again to visible or invisible status. The **visible** and **invisible** status are managed by the `isHidden` property, so the view won't be visible but it still takes space.

## Extension

```
extension UIView {

    // MARK: visibility methods

    public enum Visibility : Int {
        case visible = 0
        case invisible = 1
        case gone = 2
        case goneY = 3
        case goneX = 4
    }

    public var visibility: Visibility {
        set {
            switch newValue {
                case .visible:
                    isHidden = false
                    getConstraintY(false)?.isActive = false
                    getConstraintX(false)?.isActive = false
                case .invisible:
                    isHidden = true
                    getConstraintY(false)?.isActive = false
                    getConstraintX(false)?.isActive = false
                case .gone:
                    isHidden = true
                    getConstraintY(true)?.isActive = true
                    getConstraintX(true)?.isActive = true
                case .goneY:
                    isHidden = true
                    getConstraintY(true)?.isActive = true
                    getConstraintX(false)?.isActive = false
                case .goneX:
                    isHidden = true
                    getConstraintY(false)?.isActive = false
                    getConstraintX(true)?.isActive = true
            }
        }
        get {
            if isHidden == false {
                return .visible
            }
            if getConstraintY(false)?.isActive == true && getConstraintX(false)?.isActive == true {
                return .gone
            }
            if getConstraintY(false)?.isActive == true {
                return .goneY
            }
            if getConstraintX(false)?.isActive == true {
                return .goneX
            }
            return .invisible
        }
    }

    fileprivate func getConstraintY(_ createIfNotExists: Bool = false) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return getConstraint(.height, createIfNotExists)
    }

    fileprivate func getConstraintX(_ createIfNotExists: Bool = false) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        return getConstraint(.width, createIfNotExists)
    }

    fileprivate func getConstraint(_ attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute, _ createIfNotExists: Bool = false) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        let identifier = "random_id"
        var result: NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
        for constraint in constraints {
            if constraint.identifier == identifier {
                result = constraint
                break
            }
        }
        if result == nil && createIfNotExists {
            // create and add the constraint
            result = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: attribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 0)
            result?.identifier = identifier
            addConstraint(result!)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
myView.visibility = .visible
myView.visibility = .invisible
myView.visibility = .gone
myView.visibility = .goneX
myView.visibility = .goneY
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update your **view**'s visibility you can use the property called "isVisible"

```
myCustomView?.isVisible
```

If you need to see if the view is still part of the view hierarchy you can check using the subviews property from the super view that should contain that view

```
myController.view.subviews.contains(myCustomView)
```

Other aspects to take into consideration

```
myCustomView?.alpha = 0 //(visible but transparent)
myCustomView == nil //(not initialized)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIView {

    func visiblity(gone: Bool, dimension: CGFloat = 0.0, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute = .height) -> Void {
        if let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == attribute}.first) {
            constraint.constant = gone ? 0.0 : dimension
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.isHidden = gone
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaboration of Farshid roohi's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130160/826946.

What you want to do is create a constraint in the Storyboard that defines the height of your field. If you're not using a fixed height, it will be more complicated, but you should get the idea from this answer.
So you create a height constraint for your field.
Then you create an IBOutlet for your constraint in your code that looks something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myItemsHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

In Storyboard, you select your constraint, then connect its referencing outlet to the variable you just defined above. It's just like creating a referencing outlet for a view, but your selection in the Storyboard navigator on the left should be on the actual constraint, not the view you are constraining.

Now in your code, when you want the item to be GONE, you set:

```
myItemsHeight.constant = 0
```

When you want it to be visible, you set its height to whatever the height should be.

If you want to be fancier and leave all your layout info in the Storyboard, you could create two height constraints, one whose value is 0 and one whose value is the height you want. Then in your code, when you want the item to be GONE, you would do something like:

```
myItemGoneConstraint.priority = 1000
myItemVisibleConstraint.priority = 0
```

and do the reverse when you want it to be visible